# Hyphenated key names in react props

Tags: json, reactjs, react-props

I have a JSON payload which contains hyphenated key names which I cannot seem to access when using `this.props`

I know in JS you cant access:
`data: {name-last: dave}` with `.` notation i.e. `data.name-last` wont work but `data['name-last']` does work.

The problem I have is that when in react and using `this.props.data['name-last']` always returns undefined.

Ideally id like to not have to change the payload (as id have to modify this on the fly) is there anyway to use hyphenated key names within props?

This is an example data structure;

```
{
    generatedTime: "2017-12-08T15:04:16.876Z",
    audits: {
        first-meaningful-paint: {
            score: 85,
            displayValue: "2,370 ms",
            rawValue: 2369.9,
            optimalValue: "< 1,600 ms",
            extendedInfo: {
                value: {}
            },
            scoringMode: "numeric",
            name: "first-meaningful-paint",
            category: "Performance",
            description: "First meaningful paint",
            helpText: "First meaningful paint measures when the primary content of a page is visible. [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/first-meaningful-paint)."
        },
        speed-index-metric: {
            score: 86,
            displayValue: "2,610",
            rawValue: 2610,
            optimalValue: "< 1,250",
            extendedInfo: {},
            scoringMode: "numeric",
            name: "speed-index-metric",
            category: "Performance",
            description: "Perceptual Speed Index",
            helpText: "Speed Index shows how quickly the contents of a page are visibly populated. [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/speed-index)."
        }
    }
}
```

The above is all stored in `this.props` how can I access `this.props.data['first-set-of-data']`

I use this call:
`this.props.service.hindi["speed-index-metric"].score`

**Update**, so I have just realised that this data is not available right away. The redux store initiates with just a blank object. the `audits` object I am trying to access is pulled in after via an async request. So I am trying to access props that do not exist on the first call to `this.props` which is why the application fails on its first run.

is there anyway to let the props gracefully fail if the data doesn't exists on the first load? on does my initial state need to match the full structured state after the data is fetched?

Comment: `this.props.data['first-set-of-data']` is the right way of accessing that. What problem are you facing in accessing like that?

Comment: Hi Prakash please see my update.